# Populate Jquery Autocomplete With Google Contacts

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-contacts-api

**Is there any way to populate Jquery autocomplete list with Google Contacts?** So far I've been using the following code which **populates the autocomplete list with the values form a Google Spreadsheet** to show username suggestions and user profile pictures but **I would really like to use my Google Contact as a data source**. How should I change the code to achieve that?

**Autocomplete.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" />
</div>

<script>
// This code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildTagList)
      .getAvailableTags();
});

function buildTagList(availableTags) {
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  })
  .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li><div><img src='"+item.img+"'><span>"+item.value+"</span></div></li>" ).appendTo( ul );
  };
}
</script>
```

**getAvailableTags()**

```
function getAvailableTags() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0Avt7ejriwlxudGZfV2xJUGJZLXktm2RhQU1uRUgtaXc");
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Options");
  var data = s.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = 1; // number of header rows to skip at top
  var tagColumn = 0; // column # (0-based) containing tag

  var availableTags = [];
  for (var row=headers; row < data.length; row++) {
  var value = data[row][tagColumn];
  var url = data[row][tagColumn + 1];  // In this modification, it supposes that URLs are put in the column "B".
  availableTags.push({id: value, value: value, label: value, img: url});
}

  return( availableTags );
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question and script, I cannot understand about `Is there any way to populate Jquery autocomplete list with Google Contacts?`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Dear @Tanaike, sorry for not making it clear enough. Right know I'm using Jquery autocomplete with a Google Spreadsheet as a data source. So any time I start typing a contact name into an input field I get autocomplete suggestions which are found in my Spreadsheet. But instead of using Google Sheets I'd like to be able to use my Google Contact as a data source for autocomplete. That way it's gonna be less messier for me in the future.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood that you want to use the values from Google Contacts as the value of autocomplete. In that case, what kind of values do you want to use? I cannot understand about the values from `populates the autocomplete list with the values form a Google Spreadsheet to show username suggestions and user profile pictures`.

Comment: Dear @Tanaike, with my current code any time I type, let's say, the name "John", I get a bunch of autocomplete suggestion with full names of every John from the Column A of my data source Spreadsheet (eg. "John Lennon", "John Wayne", "John Kennedy"). I also get their pictures form the Column B, since the column has picture URLs. I'd like to achieve the same results but by using [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/) as a data source istead of Google Sheets.

Comment: Sort of like when you add a comment to a Spreadsheet cell and type "@" - you get a dropdown list with your avaliable Google Contacts that you can search. I'd like to be able to have a similar access to my Google Contacts but via the input field and without typing the "@" symbol

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your 1st request of `with my current code any time I type, let's say, the name "John", I get a bunch of autocomplete suggestion with full names of every John from the Column A of my data source Spreadsheet (eg. "John Lennon", "John Wayne", "John Kennedy"),,,`, I think that it can be achieved. About your 2nd request of `Sort of like when you add a comment to a Spreadsheet cell and type "@",,,`, unfortunately, I cannot understand. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Dear @Tanaike, no worries. English is not my first language either so I get you. But you understood me correctly - all I need is to be able to use my Google Contacts (not Google Spreadsheet) as a data source for my autocomplete suggestions

Comment: Thank you for replying. It seems that in the current stage, the photo image of each user cannot be retrieved using Contacts Service. In this case, the fullname and email can be retrieved. When the method of people.connections.list of People API is used, the photo image can be retrieved. But the official document says `Provides a list of the authenticated user's contacts.`. How about this? And, about your 2nd request of `Sort of like when you add a comment to a Spreadsheet cell and type "@",,,`, unfortunately, I cannot still understand. I apologize for this.

Comment: Dear @Tanaike, `When the method of people.connections.list of People API is used, the photo image can be retrieved. But the official document says Provides a list of the authenticated user's contacts.` - I guess that's what I'm looking for. Could you please give me some code reference? Because I've never worked with any APIs, including People API, and have no idea how to connect it with my code

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? But unfortunately, I'm not sure whether the modified script is the same direction you expect. So if that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- From the discussions in the comments, you want to retrieve the user name and user photo image using People API.

  - When the method of people.connections.list of People API is used, the official document says `Provides a list of the authenticated user's contacts`. In this case, you want to use this data.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Sample script:

In this case, please modify `getAvailableTags()` as follows. Before you use this script, [please enable People API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
function getAvailableTags() {
  const contacts = People.People.Connections.list("people/me", {personFields: "names,photos", pageSize: 1000}).connections;
  const res = contacts.reduce((ar, c) => {
    if (c.hasOwnProperty("names") && c.hasOwnProperty("photos")) {
      const name = c.names[0].displayName;
      const img = c.photos.filter(p => p.default)[0];
      ar.push({id: name, value: name, label: name, img: img.url});
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  return res;
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, `pageSize` uses `1000`. When the number of your contacts is over 1000. Please tell me.

#### Reference:

- [Method: people.connections.list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list)

### Added:

About your 2nd question of `Could I please also ask you to show me how to pull another values from my Contacts? For instance If I decide to also include email and phone number, how should I do so? I would like it to look something like this - picture on the left and the name, email, phone number each in new line.`. I would like to answer as follows.
In this case, please modify above sample script as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function getAvailableTags() {
  const contacts = People.People.Connections.list("people/me", {personFields: "names,photos,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers", pageSize: 1000}).connections;
  const res = contacts.reduce((ar, c) => {
    if (c.hasOwnProperty("names") && c.hasOwnProperty("photos")) {
      const name = c.names[0].displayName;
      const img = c.photos.filter(p => p.default)[0];
      let value = name;
      if (c.hasOwnProperty("emailAddresses")) value += "<br>" + c.emailAddresses[0].value;
      if (c.hasOwnProperty("phoneNumbers")) value += "<br>" + c.phoneNumbers[0].value;
      ar.push({id: name, value: value, label: name, img: img.url});
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Dear @Tanaike, the code works great! Thank you very much! Could I please also ask you to show me **how to pull another values from my Contacts?** For instance If I decide to also include email and phone number, how should I do so? I would like it to look something like [this](https://storage.googleapis.com/support-forums-api/attachment/thread-12835507-1759212256541634530.PNG) - picture on the left and the name, email, phone number each in new line. Thank you very much again.

Comment: @Michael Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your replying, I could understand that your question was resolved. About your new question, I added the answer in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If my understanding of your 2nd question is not correct, I apologize.

Comment: Dear @Tanaike, I've only now noticed tiny issues with your 2nd modification of the script: while it allows me to search an autocomplete item by its **name**, I can't search it by its **email**. For example, if I have a contact named "John Wayne" with the email "info@coolcowboy.com" **I can only find it if I start typing its name** but I'd also like to be able to find it **by typing it's email**. Another problem is that the final value that I'm getting **includes html symbols**, so it looks like: `"John Wayne<br>info@coolcowboy.com"`. Is there any way to solve these issues? Thank you very much

Comment: @Michael About your 2 new questions, unfortunately, I have to apologize that I cannot answer for them soon. This is due to my poor skill. Although I have already been able to resolve your 2 questions, I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your 2 more new questions soon. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your all questions. So in this case, can you post it as new questions? By this, it will help users think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your 2 new questions, I'm glad. I deeply apologize for my much poor skill again. I would like to study more and more.

Comment: Dear @Tanaike, I've managed to solve the issues, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Michael Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.