# Number of items in array of contacts from People.People.Connections.list() doesn't match totalItems, doesn't contain all contacts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

I'm working Google Apps Script. I can obtain all of my Google Contacts using the People API method People.People.Connections.list(). The response body contains an array of People called Connections, and an integer representing the total number of contacts returned, called totalItems (among other things).

When I run the following test,

```
function getConnections() {
  try {
    // Get the list of connections/contacts of user's profile
    var people = People.People.Connections.list('people/me', {
      personFields: 'names'
    });

    //Display the whole list
    Logger.log('Connections: %s', JSON.stringify(people, null, 2));
  } catch (err) {
    Logger.log('Failed to get the connection with an error %s', err.message);
  }

  Logger.log(`totalItems: ${people.totalItems}`);
  Logger.log(`length of people.connections: ${people.connections.length}`);

  //Output the names of all the People in people.connections.
  for(i = 0; i < people.connections.length ;i++){
    if(people.connections[i] && people.connections[i].names){
      Logger.log(i + " " + people.connections[i].names[0].displayName);
    }
    else {Logger.log("Something wrong with contact?")}
  }
}
```

Logger outputs:

> Info  totalItems: 155

> Info  length of people.connections: 100

The for loop outputs the connection's names just fine, those that exist in the array anyway.
Does anyone have any insight into this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The default value of `pageSize` of "Method: people.connections.list" is 100. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list)I think that the reason for your current issue is due to this. I thought that those sample scripts will be answers. https://stackoverflow.com/q/64408074 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/70527498

Comment: Well, I feel like an idiot. It's right there on the documentation page for the method. I didn't even know enough to know what to search for! Thank you.